# Paste event not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying out this simple code. What I want is that when a `paste` event is fired on the second input textbox, it should be cleared, after copying its contents, removing the `readonly` attribute of the previous textbox, and pasting it there. however, nothing is happening.

The `paste` event is fired alright, because if I replace the code in the timer by a simple `alert`, it works. Can anyone tell me what's wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".boo").bind("input paste",function() { 
         elem = this;
         setTimeout(function() { 
             $(".foo").removeAttr("readonly");
             $(".foo").text($(elem).text());
             $(elem).text("");  
         },100);
        });
      });
  </script>
</head>
 <body>
   <input class = 'foo' type = 'text' /><input class = 'boo' type = 'text' />
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use val() instead of text() for input:text

Comment: Declare "elem" with `var`!!

Comment: Well, did that (I can't believe that I was using `text` instead of `val`!). However, now the 2nd textbox is being cleared, but the first textbox isn't populated with its value...

Comment: That's because you're explicitly setting the value of "elem" to the empty string!

Comment: Yeah, definitely I would declare elem with `var` in the final code. This is just for testing purpose..

Comment: That's really a silly way to go about things. You don't just do it for cosmetic purposes; it makes a serious difference to the semantics of the code.

Comment: @Pointy, but that is after I have filled the first box with the 2nd box's value, right?

Comment: Are you still using `.text()` instead of `.val()` to get the **value** of the other input?

Comment: The `var` thing? I know that, mate. I just coded as much required to find out this specific bug..

Comment: No, now I have replaced all `text()` with `val()`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you should use `.val()` instead of `.text()` with input control.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("input.boo").bind("paste", function () { //also changed the binding too
        var elem = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".foo").val(elem.val());
            elem.val("");
        }, 100);
    });

});
```

Also, your bound event(s) were fired twice when text is pasted in the control. That's because, you have bound both `input` and `paste` events to the element(s) with "boo" class.

So here, instead of:

```
$(".boo").bind("input paste", function() {});
```

Use this:

```
$("input.boo").bind("paste", function() {});
```

This will bind only the `paste` event to input elements with "boo" class.

See **updated** [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/onury/JRTU6/).

Comment: Like I said above, try it. The 2nd box is getting cleared immediately, but the first box is not getting its value...

Comment: Why wasn't the previous version working? What's wrong with that?

Comment: yeah, it's working in Fiddle. Dunno, I am trying at http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide, it's not working..

Comment: Why? Why do we need to reference it before the timer is set?

Comment: Yeah, I know those fundas, but how do they apply here? I mean, if you get the value within the timer, when it is called after 100 ms, the value is still what was pasted, right? Only after it is explicitly cleared is when the value won't be accessible. What has execution context got to do with it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23016/discussion-between-onur-yildirim-and-cupidvogel)